# Is there a way to anonymize user data on Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an app that uses the signInWithEmailAndPassword from Firebase to signin users. Is it possible to hide the data shown in the Firebase Authentication tab with a list of all emails and linking to their id tokens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion that is not possible.
I've done a research and nothing points me to this. I think this is more related to the internal security of the firebase itself, and how google manage it. On the other hand you, the administrator, are the only person who has access to this data, and i'm pretty sure there are legal lines that restricts and protects theese credentials.

Comment: Yeah, I've searched too and couldn't really find anything. I might be wrong but I think that ideally you shouldn't be able to link emails and token id's, even with administrator access

Comment: Well, you have a point. I think this is a great question to ask firebase/google and maybe they will be happy to answear.

Comment: in my opinion, to anonimize auth data you have to delete the email address. In this case there is no reason to be kept auth data.  Then I keep only user instance in my dababase but delete the user in Firebase authentification